# least upper bounds that are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, coprime

Given $n$ natural numbers $p_1$, $p_2$, ... $p_n$ find numbers $q_1$, $q_2$, ... $q_n$ that are pairwise coprimes such that $p_i$ ≤ $q_i$ and such that $\prod_{i=1..n} q_i$ is smallest possible.

I come from programing background. When I try to phrase this in my computer science language, then the question would be:
I have integer sided hyper rectangle. How do I find smallest (with respect to volume) integer sided hyper rectangle which contains my hyper rectangle such that greatest common divisor of any two side lengths equals to one.

Comment: So... for interest's sake, have you calculated this for any non-trivial cases - say $\{p_i\} = \{32,34,36,38,40\}$?

Comment: What I do now is incrementing each number until it is coprime with all previous. For your input this procedure returns {32,34,37,39,41}.

Comment: @Joffan I also have a heuristic. I sort $p_i$ from smallest to largest before running above described procedure. However I still suspect this might not return optimal solution. But I am not sure. I don't have neither proof it is optimal nor counter example.